# @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS) no transaction is in progress

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-transactions

I have a simple CRUD project.
I have a simple CRUD project with Hibernate 5 and Spring Boot. When I use `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)`, I catch the error `javax.persistence.transactionrequiredexception: no transaction is in progress`. When I use the `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)`, everything is fine.
What I doing wrong?

Repository:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
public Toy getToy(String companyName, String toyName) throws Exception {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    try {
        Query query = session.createQuery("from Toy where company.name = :company and name = :name");
        query.setParameter("company", companyName);
        query.setParameter("name", toyName);
        return (Toy) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        Toy toy = new Toy();
        Query query = session.createQuery("from  Company where name = :name");
        query.setParameter("name", companyName);
        Company company = (Company) query.getSingleResult();
        toy.setCompany(company);
        toy.setName(templateName);
        toy.bought(0);
        toy.setViewed(0);
        return toy;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REQUIRED is the default propagation. Spring checks if there is an active transaction, then it creates a new one if nothing existed. Otherwise, the business logic appends to the currently active transaction.

SUPPORTS, Spring first checks if an active transaction exists. If a transaction exists, then the existing transaction will be used. If there isn't a transaction, it is executed non-transactional.

So you got this error simply because no transaction exists when entering inside the method wrap by "SUPPORT-propagation" transaction.

By the way SUPPORTS have very limited use-cases... most of the time using default "REQUIRED" offers exactly what we need.

Comment: I do not understand. If a transaction does not exist, why is an error thrown instead of executing without a transaction? After all, this is SUPPORTS, not MANDATORY.
I have get requests, and I want the transaction to not be created to execute them, because of this, the server response time increases. This is especially true for highly loaded applications.

Comment: because with hibernate transaction are required when writing to the database

Comment: I attached the repository code, I call this method from the test

Comment: As your queries are read-only , you should switch to read-only transaction `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS,  readOnly="true")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped!